# Pip install success but import statement ModuleNotFoundError also Anaconda & PyCharm interference

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am new to Python and pip install. Basically, my `pip install tweepy` is successful but my `import tweepy` is not.
I am running this version of python:

> Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC
>   v.1900 64  bit (AMD64)] on win32

After i did pip install, there was a long block of code and these were the last two lines

```
  
Successfully built oauthlib
Installing collected packages: oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, tweepy
Successfully installed oauthlib-2.0.6 requests-oauthlib-0.8.0 tweepy-3.5.0
```

I found a tweepy folder inside my directory
 `C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`

and inside a project, which is using PyCharm as an IDE, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Student/Desktop/Code/Python/Node1.py", line 1, in 
    import tweepy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

however, importing a default library, such as  `import random`  works fine. I should note that  `import tweepy`  works when I use jupyter notebook, but I want to use PyCharm for now. How do I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Do You have it installed in the Interpreter used in a project? 
`File->Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`
`import` You want should be installed there

Comment: Sorry, what am I supposed to be looking for? Pip is there, as well as setuptools and wheel. Now what?

Comment: You can press green plus on rigth and add needed modules, this is gui for pip. You are looking for `tweepy` on the list, if it is not there then add it.